# Deploying Python Lambda Functions in AWS Codepipeline using AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

So I am trying to deploy some lambda functions through Codepipeline using Amazon's new Cloud Development Kit in Typescript. The issue is that for the Build stage of my pipeline, the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/codepipeline_example.html#codepipeline_example_create)  only provide an example for building lambda functions written in typescript. I know this is probably a simple issue for someone more experienced with build specs but I was wondering if someone could provide me with the equivalent buildspec for Python lambdas.

I have pasted the code below that defines the pipeline I am trying to create. The cdkBuild works fine but I am having trouble coming up with the proper commands for install, prebuild, and build with the buildspec for lambdaBuild.

```
const cdkBuild = new codebuild.PipelineProject(this, 'CdkBuild', {
      buildSpec: codebuild.BuildSpec.fromObject({
        version: '0.2',
        phases: {
          install: {
            commands: 'npm install',
          },
          build: {
            commands: [
              'npm run build',
              'npm run cdk synth -- -o dist'
            ],
          },
        },
        artifacts: {
          'base-directory': 'dist',
          files: [
            'AdminStack.template.json',
          ],
        },
      }),
      environment: {
        buildImage: codebuild.LinuxBuildImage.STANDARD_2_0,
      },
    });

    const lambdaBuild = new codebuild.PipelineProject(this, 'LambdaBuild', {
      buildSpec: codebuild.BuildSpec.fromObject({
        version: '0.2',
        phases: {
          install: {
            commands: [
              /*'python3 -m venv .venv',
              'source .venv/bin/activate',*/
              'pip install -r requirements.txt -t lambda' 
            ],
          },
          build: {
            //commands: 'npm run build',
          },
        },
        artifacts: {
          'base-directory': 'lambda',
          files: [
            'admin/tutors/put.py ',
            'requirements.txt',
          ],
        },
      }),
      environment: {
        buildImage: codebuild.LinuxBuildImage.STANDARD_2_0,
      },
    });

    const sourceOutput = new codepipeline.Artifact();
    const cdkBuildOutput = new codepipeline.Artifact('CdkBuildOutput');
    const lambdaBuildOutput = new codepipeline.Artifact('LambdaBuildOutput');
    const pipeline = new codepipeline.Pipeline(this, 'BackendPipeline', {
      stages: [
        {
          stageName: 'Source',
          actions: [
            new codepipeline_actions.CodeCommitSourceAction({
              actionName: 'CodeCommit_Source',
              repository: code,
              output: sourceOutput,
            }),
          ],
        },
        {
          stageName: 'Build',
          actions: [
            new codepipeline_actions.CodeBuildAction({
              actionName: 'Lambda_Build',
              project: lambdaBuild,
              input: sourceOutput,
              outputs: [lambdaBuildOutput],
            }),
            new codepipeline_actions.CodeBuildAction({
              actionName: 'CDK_Build',
              project: cdkBuild,
              input: sourceOutput,
              outputs: [cdkBuildOutput],
            }),
          ],
        },
        {
          stageName: 'Deploy',
          actions: [
            new codepipeline_actions.CloudFormationCreateUpdateStackAction({
              actionName: 'AdminStack_CFN_Deploy',
              templatePath: cdkBuildOutput.atPath('AdminStack.template.json'),
              stackName: 'AdminStack',
              adminPermissions: true,
              parameterOverrides: {
                ...props.lambdaCode.assign(lambdaBuildOutput.s3Location),
              },
              extraInputs: [lambdaBuildOutput],
            }),
          ],
        },
      ],
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you do not need to use a virtual environment.
The artifacts should be what would be in the *.zip* you upload if you create a lambda manually which are the required libraries as well as your own code. Assuming all your python lambda code and the requirements.txt is under */lambda*, the buildspec part should look like this:

```
codebuild.BuildSpec.fromObject({
            version: '0.2',
            phases: {
              build: {
                'pip install -r lambda/requirements.txt -t lambda'
              },
            },
            artifacts: {
              'base-directory': 'lambda',
              files: [
                '**/*'
              ],
            },
          }),
          environment: {
            buildImage: codebuild.LinuxBuildImage.STANDARD_2_0,
          },
});
```